# codeigniter ion auth forget password

Tags: codeigniter, forgot-password, ion-auth

i'm using codeigniter & ion auth. I'm having problem trying to send out email to user.

this is working:

```
$message = 'hello';
$this->email->from($this->config->item('admin_email', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth'));
$this->email->to($user->email);
$this->email->subject($this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('email_forgotten_password_subject'));
$this->email->message($message);
```

when i change to use tpl, it is not working:
/views/forgot_password.tpl.php

```
$message = $this->load->view('forgot_password.tpl.php', $data, TRUE);
$this->email->from($this->config->item('admin_email', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth'));
$this->email->to($user->email);
$this->email->subject($this->config->item('site_title', 'ion_auth') . ' - ' . $this->lang->line('email_forgotten_password_subject'));
$this->email->message($message);
```

pls advise, thanks.

Comment: Your missing the path to the view file? By default it is `auth/email/forgot_password.tpl.php`

Comment: my template is located @ .../views/forgot_password.tpl.php

Comment: Have you tried debugging it ? Add `echo $message; die();` after the `$this->load->view()` line, and see if it is in fact getting the view file.

If that seems fine, next you may want to try a `print_r($data);die();` to see if your passing all the data it needs.

Comment: Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/demo/forgot_password/process. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Comment: You get that error from adding in the line `echo $message;die();`?

Comment: Sounds like you may have bigger problems. Are you sure it was working with just `$message = 'test';` ? Do you have error logging enabled in codeigniter/php ?

Comment: yes, confirmed it is working with $message = 'test';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "forgot_password.tpl.php" to "forgot_password.tpl" in your code:

```
$message = $this->load->view('forgot_password.tpl.php', $data, TRUE);
```

You don't need .php in $this->load->view().